# Animate a tube cylinder with "build" modifier - problem with round shape

Tags: build-modifier

I'm trying to recreate this animation: https://laravel.com/img/hero/hero.mp4

I've got 2 tubes one inside the other (`bezier curves` + `bevel` attribute to make them thick).
Since I need to animate the internal tube (the colored one), I'm using the `build modifier`.

The problem is that the build modifier create the shape in a strange way similar to "wall brick building" (check the screenshot), while I need the tube to animate as it is made by water (so the internal tube grow parallel to the circumference), so smooth filling of the tube.

**Any idea/suggestion on how to proceed?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the build modifier, use the bezier's bevel end property.

After adding a bevel object or increasing the *depth*, you can change the **Bevel End value** and animate it by hovering over the property and pressing <kbd>I</kbd> or clicking on the circle to its right.

[image: bevel end]

Comment: thanks!! that's what I needed

Answer (score 2):

You want to animate the Bevel property of a curve, not use the Build modifier. Turn on Fill Caps.

[image]

Comment: thanks!! that's what I needed